# How to know number of cores of a system in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu

I wanted to find out how many cores my system has, so I searched the same question in Google. I got some commands such as the `lscpu` command.
When I tried this command, it gave me the following result:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               1998.000
BogoMIPS:              5302.48
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

In particular, this output shows:

- CPU(s): 4
- Core(s) per socket: 4
- CPU family: 6

Which of those indicates cores of a Linux system?

Is there any other command to tell the number of cores, or am I assuming it is completely wrong?

Comment: my simple command for all users: $ grep precessor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: @สมหวังแนวหน้า kind of a nitpick, but the the grep arg should be `processor`, not `precessor`, correct? . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You have to look at sockets and cores per socket. In this case you have 1 physical CPU (socket) which has 4 cores (cores per socket).

Comment: I have one socket, two cpus per socket, so that would mean a total of 2. However, it says 4 cpus. If I try `nproc` I get 4 back. Using `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I get 4, and thus it seems this answer is wrong, for my situation at least.

Comment: Not if you have hyper threading. You still have 2 physical cores but each core shows in /proc/cpuinfo twice. If you look carefully under coreid you can see that you have each coreid listed twice. Also under flags you can see the ht flag.

Comment: So what does `CPU(s): 4` refer to in this case?

Comment: CPU (s) is the number of logical CPUs. If a cpu has hyperthreading enabled then this number is higher than the number of actual cores.

Answer (score 367):

To get a complete picture you need to look at the number of [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) per core, [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) per socket and [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket). If you multiply these numbers you will get the number of [CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) on your system.

> CPUs = Threads per core X cores per socket X sockets

CPUs are what you see when you run `htop` (these do not equate to physical CPUs).

Here is an example from a desktop machine:

```
$ lscpu | grep -E '^Thread|^Core|^Socket|^CPU\('
CPU(s):                8
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
```

And a server:

```
$ lscpu | grep -E '^Thread|^Core|^Socket|^CPU\('
CPU(s):                32
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
```

The output of `nproc` corresponds to the CPU count from `lscpu`. For the desktop machine above this should match the 8 CPU(s) reported by `lscpu`:

```
$ nproc --all
8
```

The output of `/proc/cpuinfo` should match this information, for example on the desktop system above we can see there are 8 processors (CPUs) and 4 cores (core id 0-3):

```
$ grep -E 'processor|core id' /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
core id     : 0
processor   : 1
core id     : 0
processor   : 2
core id     : 1
processor   : 3
core id     : 1
processor   : 4
core id     : 2
processor   : 5
core id     : 2
processor   : 6
core id     : 3
processor   : 7
core id     : 3
```

The `cpu cores` reported by `/proc/cpuinfo` corresponds to the `Core(s) per socket` reported by `lscpu`. For the desktop machine above this should match the 4 Core(s) per socket reported by lscpu:

```
$ grep -m 1 'cpu cores' /proc/cpuinfo
cpu cores   : 4
```

To specifically answer your question you tell how many cores you have by multiplying the number of cores you have per socket by the number of sockets you have.

> Cores = Cores per socket X Sockets

For the example systems above the desktop has 4 cores:

```
$ echo "Cores = $(( $(lscpu | awk '/^Socket\(s\)/{ print $2 }') * $(lscpu | awk '/^Core\(s\) per socket/{ print $4 }') ))"
Cores = 4
```

While the server has 16:

```
$ echo "Cores = $(( $(lscpu | awk '/^Socket\(s\)/{ print $2 }') * $(lscpu | awk '/^Core\(s\) per socket/{ print $4 }') ))"
Cores = 16
```

Another useful utility is `dmidecode` which outputs per socket information. In the case of the server system listed above we expect to see 8 cores per socket and 16 threads per socket:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep -E 'Socket Designation|Count'
    Socket Designation: CPU1
    Core Count: 8
    Thread Count: 16
    Socket Designation: CPU2
    Core Count: 8
    Thread Count: 16
```

The `lscpu` command has a number of useful options that you may like to check out, for example:

```
$ lscpu --all --extended
$ lscpu --all --parse=CPU,SOCKET,CORE | grep -v '^#'
```

See `man lscpu` for details.

In summary:

- You need to be aware of sockets, cores and threads
- You need to be careful of the term CPU as it means different things in different contexts

Comment: In CentOS 6.x, `dmidecode` does not output Core/Thread count info, and it actually regards 'CPU' as 'CPU' or 'Core' in lscpu, not 'socket'.

Comment: I think adding `lscpu --all --extended` would be a useful addition but I no longer have access to these particular machines.

Comment: You can also avoid awk and an explicit multiplication: `lscpu --all --parse=CORE,SOCKET | grep -Ev "^#" | sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: @Jakub Klinkovský, thanks for pointing that out but in this case I want to actually demonstrate the multiplication of `Socket(s) * Core(s) per socket`. Given what I just said I guess `echo Cores = $(( $(lscpu | awk '/^Socket\(s\)/{ print $2 }') * $(lscpu | awk '/^Core\(s\) per socket/{ print $4 }') ))` would be better so that people can see exactly what is being multiplied ...

Comment: Thank you @htaccess for this very detailed answer. This answer should be the accepted answer and is way better for someone looking deep into this matter.

Answer (score 77):

You can get this information by [`nproc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nproc) command

```
$ nproc --all
12
```

It does not require root privileges.

Comment: This is incorrect, the output of nproc corresponds to the CPU count from lscpu. If you have multithreaded cores then the output of nproc will not match the number of cores you have.

Comment: For a non-root solution, a hack would be to use top and hit 1. This will show the number of _available_ cores. Why I saw "available" is because the underlying hardware might have more cores like a cloud infra.

Comment: @htaccess At least on Ubuntu, this outputs the correct number of on-line logical CPUs

Comment: @htaccess `nproc --all` on Ubuntu 18.04 with i5-6200U returns `4` as expected, so perhaps you can provide a little more context re *incorrect*.

Comment: @Wil the question asks "how many cores my system has" not "number of on-line logical CPUs" My laptop has 4 logical CPUs  with 1 socket, 2 cores per socket and 2 threads per core. It has 2 cores and 4 CPUs.

Comment: Just discovered `lscpu --all --extended` which gives another view of this info, might add it to my answer.

Comment: @htaccess ok I get it.  Usually when a linux duffer asks how many cores they mean how many logical threads are available.  Technically speaking, linux is wrong to call hardware threads 'cpus'.  Your machine has 1 CPU with 2 Cores and 4 SMT hardware threads.  There's a huge amount of ambiguity in what CPUs and Cores mean as a result.  But I get what you meant now, ty.

Comment: @Wil yea I call this out in my answer above: "You need to be careful of the term CPU as it means different things in different contexts". Personally I don't equate "cores" to logical processing units but to physical cores in the processor (ie the physical processing units).

Answer (score 37):

For the answer not to be confusing, you need to understand a couple of simple computer architecture concepts:

- You run **processes** ("programs") on your linux system.  Each process consists of one or more **threads**
- Each **thread** is a separate sequence of **instructions**.  Two threads can be executed in parallel.
- Each **instruction** is given to a **CPU** to be executed.  A CPU has logic that figures out what the bits of an instruction mean and decides what to do with it.
- There are different types of instructions.  The decision logic inside a CPU will dispatch the different instructions to different **hardware units**.  For instance, arithmetic instructions are actually performed by an **ALU** (arithmetic/logic unit), while instructions that load/store from memory are executed by some sort of **memory unit**.
- A **core** refers to a set of actual execution hardware (i.e. every core has an ALU, a memory unit, etc...)
- You can have multiple CPUs that share one core - this is called hyperthreading.

  - The idea: thread A is currently doing arithmetic, while thread B is loading something from memory.  When that's true, threads A and B can efficiently share a single core without getting in each other's way (A uses the ALU, B uses the memory unit).  Of course, sometimes both programs will want the ALU, and then they have to wait for each other...
- A **socket** is the physical slot on the motherboard into which a chip is inserted.  This chip has a certain number of cores on it.

## Examples:

The OP's example:

```
CPU(s):                4
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
```

- one physical socket, which contains a chip with
- 4 physical cores (think 4 ALUs and 4 memory units total)
- Only 1 thread can issue instructions to a core (no hyperthreading), which means there is
- one CPU per core, or 4 * 1 = 4 CPUs

Another example:

```
CPU(s):                16
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
```

Two physical sockets, each containing a chip with 4 physical cores, making 8 cores total.  Two threads get to issue instructions to each core (this machine has hyperthreading), meaning there must be two CPUs attached to each core, making a total of 8 * 2 = 16 CPUs

The first machine can be executing precisely four instructions at any given time, period.  The second machine can execute between 8 and 16 instructions at any given time: 16 will be achieved only when each pair of CPUs is executing different types of instructions and so can share a core without waiting.

Comment: wow thank you, that was a great explanation!

Comment: Only thing; you use "CPU" as virtual CPUs for the kernel; "normally" a CPU has multiple cores. Not wrong just confusing I want to say.

Comment: @rastafile:. it's an interesting point you raise.  different people use "CPU" to mean different things.  I believe what I say here is consistent with the output of the lscpu command which the OP referenced.  In my experience, computer engineers are referring to what you call a core when they say CPU, but even there I'm sure someone will disagree with me 

Comment: I have now 4 CPUs. Before, I had hyperthreading on (via BIOS), and it showed 8, from cpu0 to cpu7. I have one "quadcore processor", the vendor tells me on the box. Confusing, because I can easily say I have "a CPU that can run 8 threads" at a time (yes, with hyperthreading, so it is more 5 or 6 threads' equivalent).

Comment: right, so both before and after hyperthreading you had four cores.  Before, you had 8 CPUs: eight pieces of hardware that could accept instructions to be run (but with only 4 full sets of execution hardware).  By turning off hyperthreading, you disabled half of those CPUs (one CPU on each core is now disabled).  

You are certainly correct that it is a little confusing.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo` which will output a chunk of data for each core.  Each chunk starts with this info:

```
processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz
(...)
```

Cores are numbered starting from 0, so if the last chunk says `processor   : 3` as in this case, your machine has 4 cores.

Comment: Thanks this command describing the information in detail.:)

Comment: For a one-liner command, you might use `grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248063/22812, this answer only provides the correct number of cores if none of the cores have multiple concurrent threads of execution, i.e., multi-threading (SMT, HTT) is not enabled for any of the cores. On a Linux system, `/proc/cpuinfo` lists information about each *logical* CPU.

Answer (score 9):

```
getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN
```

(getconf is part of glibc)

Comment: That's slightly different (and useful for some needs).  It's the number of processors that are online now (i.e. available for running processes).  It may be less than the total number of CPUs if one or more have been taken offline (e.g. during hibernation or whilst adding/removing processors).

Comment: And `getconf _NPROCESSORS_CONF` gets you the number of processors configured. You can get the value of both these macros inside of a C source code too, by using the `sysconf()` function. Type in `man sysconf` for more information.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo
8
```

That's all you need.  It is the number of core online, regardless if hyperthreading is on or off.

```
$ ls -d /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu* | wc -l
8
```

Another easy way.

Comment: This is simple, but I'm not sure it's accurate to the question.  He asked for the number of cores: (cores != cpus) if hyperthreading is enabled.  My system has 24 cores: 48 cpus when hyper-threaded.  Also, using the second command provided `ls -d /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu* | wc -l` showed **49** because there is a directory `cpuidle` among the `cpuN` directories.

Answer (score 4):

```
[root@xxxxx ~]#  dmidecode -t 4 | egrep -i "Designation|Intel|core|thread"
    Socket Designation: CPU1
    Manufacturer: Intel
            HTT (Multi-threading)
    Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5640  @ 2.27GHz
    Core Count: 6
    Core Enabled: 6
    Thread Count: 12
    Socket Designation: CPU2
    Manufacturer: Intel
            HTT (Multi-threading)
    Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5640  @ 2.27GHz
    Core Count: 6
    Core Enabled: 6
    Thread Count: 12
```

Comment: What's the `t 4` do for dmidecode? How do the counts & enabled lines multiply out? Does your example show 2 cores, or 6, or 12, or 24, or some other number?

Comment: @Xen2050 `4` is `processor`, see https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode. But using `4` as argument is a bad practice.

Comment: `bash: dmidecode: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

I found this way:

```
echo $((`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/present | sed 's/0-//'` + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Install and run `neofetch` in the CLI.

```
`.-::---..                     jeremy@hal 
      .:++++ooooosssoo:.       ---------- 
    .+o++::.      `.:oos+.     OS: LMDE 4 (debbie) x86_64 
   :oo:.`             -+oo:    Kernel: 5.10.0-0.bpo.7-amd64 
 `+o/`    .::::::-.    .++-`   Uptime: 7 hours, 8 mins 
`/s/    .yyyyyyyyyyo:   +o-`   Packages: 2752 (dpkg) 
`so     .ss       ohyo` :s-:   Shell: bash 5.0.3 
`s/     .ss  h  m  myy/ /s``   Resolution: 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz 
`s:     `oo  s  m  Myy+-o:`    DE: Cinnamon 5.0.5 
`oo      :+sdoohyoydyso/.      WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
 :o.      .:////////++:        WM Theme: Mint-Y-Dark (Mint-Y) 
 `/++        -:::::-           Theme: Mint-Y [GTK2/3] 
  `++-                         Icons: Mint-X [GTK2/3] 
   `/+-                        Terminal: gnome-terminal 
     .+/.                      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8- (16) @ 3.800GHz 
       .:+-.                   GPU: NVIDIA NVIDIA Corporation GP108 
          `--.``               Memory: 1968MiB / 32087MiB
```

Answer (score -2):

CPU family is irrelevant here.

- CPU(s) = physical sockets
- Core(s) per socket - as it says
- so **total number of cores** = CPU(s) * Core(s) per socket

In your case, you have total 4 full cores.

What also can be important, is "Thread(s) per core". But you have 1, so not in your case.

Comment: You are confusing CPU(s) with Socket(s) in your description.

Comment: As jlliagre says this is incorrect. `Cores = Cores per socket X Sockets`, see the description in my response.

Answer (score -3):

A simple way to figure out the number of CPUs is by issuing the commands below:

```
cat /proc/interrupts | egrep -i 'cpu'
```

Comment: Interrupts, or cpuinfo?

Comment: And count with the -c option?