# Why does top show a different number of cores than cpuinfo?

Tags: linux, cpu

When I run top, I show CPU 0-7.  When i do:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | uniq
```

I get:

```
cpu cores : 4
```

If I grep "physical id" I have 1.

I am thinking my command is wrong and top is right.  This is not a VM and it a physical server, RedHat.  What am I doing wrong?

I am not sure these answer it:

[How to know number of cores of a system in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218074/how-to-know-number-of-cores-of-a-system-in-linux)

[Number of processors in /proc/cpuinfo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146051/number-of-processors-in-proc-cpuinfo)

Edit:  Am I correct that Physical ID, if it only shows 1, then I have one physical chip in the motherboard?

Edit:  It is a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz but the physical id is 1, and I thought it would be 0, but there is no physical id 0 in cpuinfo.

Edit:  If it matters, I am trying to figure out licensing where they do .5 the core count.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What CPU are you using? How many thread present per physical core?

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows number of physical core whereas `top` shows total no of threads present.

I think your CPU has 4 physical core and 2 logical core per physical core. So it's `top` showing 8.

Moreover contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` is somewhat implementation dependent. Like in rooted android shell the `cpuinfo` file doesn't contain any term `cpu cores`.

However in `cpuinfo` each thread is named as `processor : X`, Where `X` is thread no. So the last thread no shall be same as `top/htop` output.

Result of `nproc --all` shall also be consistent with `top/htop`

Comment: So what does 8 mean here?

Comment: 8 means total no of thread, marked from 0-7. `top/htop` counts `threads` as core

Comment: But how many physical chips do I have?  If I open the box, how many chips will I see?  I have a physical id of 1, but that makes me think there are actually two chips because I thought it would be zero.

Comment: http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-find-the-number-of-physical-cpus-in-linux/ this explains well how to count  number of `core`, `thread` and `physical cpu`

Comment: I used that before posting.  But I have physical id 1.

Comment: Yah. `Physical ID` indicates number of `physical CPU cheap` you've on motherboard, `physical core` or `core` indicate number of `physical core` inside a single `CPU cheap` and `thread` means number of `logical` ( i.e. `virtual`) core inside a physical core. You shall have one `CPU` on motherboard so the result is 1.

Comment: What is CPU "cheap"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69085/discussion-between-abhik-bose-and-johnny).

Comment: In my case (a Proxmox container (or a VM?)) `nproc --all` return 4 but `htop` only show one CPU bar.

Answer (score 27):

The X5560 is a single *chip*.  It looks like this:

[image]

`grep "physical id"` is telling you that you have ONE physical processor installed.

If you take the heat spreader off of the top you can see this - a single physical *die* (face down) :

[image]

If you could remove that die and flip it over, it would look like this :

[image]

On that single physical die there are four *physical CPU cores* built onto the silicon :

[image]

`grep "cpu cores"` is telling you that your processor has four physical cores built onto it.

Each core is a single processor with a floating point unit, a number of integer execution units, a pair of register stacks, and some other wizardry that allows each single core to effectively execute two independent instruction streams (threads) at a time.

[image]

`top` is telling you that all the processors and cores on your computer, collectively, can execute eight independent workflows at a time - it's telling you that the operating system is able to schedule eight simultaneous threads for execution at any given time.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I really appreciate your time on this.  Helps me a great deal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it two threads?  How do they get two?  Why not four or five, silly as that sounds.

Comment: @johnny Most cpus for most of time have been one chip, one core, one thread.  Over time engineers noticed that some parts of a core spend a significant amount of time idle while they are waiting for other parts to finish their work.  Hyperthreading is a relatively new technology that adds a few extra bits to the core to allow more of those previously idle parts to remain mostly busy most of the time by feeding them a separate independent workload. It doesn't double the performance of a core, but it does allow it to do about 30% more work than it otherwise would, so the buck stops there at two.

Answer (score 7):

`top` shows one “CPU” per logical CPU; on x86, that’s the product of the number of sockets in the system, by the number of physical cores per socket, by the number of threads per core.

The `cpu cores` entry in `/proc/cpuinfo`, again on x86, shows the number of physical cores. To find the number of logical cores, as used in `top`, you should look at the `siblings` value instead:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "siblings" | uniq
```

This is described in detail in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/topology.txt).

`lscpu` provides information on the installed CPU(s) which is easier to understand than `/proc/cpuinfo` (or rather, it presents the same information in a simpler fashion).

Answer (score 4):

Likely, you have one CPU that is a "quad core" CPU, and have hyperthreading enabled so that each physical core presents itself to the OS (to the kernel) as two *logical* cores, able to have two threads assigned to that same physical core simultaneously.

The key terms to ensure you understand here are: CPU, or physical chip, or "die" (relates to "socket"); then, physical core; then ensure you have a grasp on "process" and "thread"; then clear up "hyperthreading" and "logical core."

I attended a talk at LISA 2017 that cleared this all up very nicely; the slides from that talk [are available online](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/18ZCIDxEQHCL1yYFckx-6u4DwNGfR-_803EQphIENpHc), though of course they won't help *as much* as the actual talk did (since the spoken part is missing).

Answer (score 2):

cpuinfo show the actual cores while htop/top show both cores and thread as cores.You most likely have 4 cores and 4 threads that's why.

Comment: I'm about ready to open the box and look!

Comment: You have 8 threads that's why top shows 8